# convert milliseconds to AM and PM date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am storing `TIMESTAMP` in database and when i fetch it back from database i want to convert it into AM and PM date format.

```
 var dbDate = moment(milliseconds); // **i am getting an error over here** 
 var data = dbDate.format("hh:mm:A").split(":");
```

but i am getting following error `moment(milliseconds);`

> "Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment library, by default, only supports a limited number of formats within the constructor.  If you don't use one of those formats, it defaults back to using `new Date`, where [browsers are free to interpret the given date how they choose](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) unless it fits certain criteria.

The deprecation warning is there to warn you of this behaviour - it's not necessarily an error.

In your case, you have milliseconds, so you can use the [moment constructor that has a format parameter](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), telling it you're specifically passing in milliseconds:

```
var dbDate = moment(milliseconds, 'x');
```

All this assumes that you currently have  `milliseconds` being returned to your JavaScript layer as a String.  If you return it and treat it as a Number, you shouldn't be seeing that warning, as moment also has a [specific constructor that takes a single Number](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/), which if your `milliseconds` parameter is a Number should be being used already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with moment.js but from a quick look in the docs I don't think the constructor supports a milliseconds argument. Try this:

```
var dbDate = moment({milliseconds: milliseconds});
```

### edit

The above code might just treat that as the value after the decimal point in the seconds - if so try this:

```
var dbDate = moment(new Date(milliseconds));
```

Comment: its returning invalid date `var dbDate = moment(new Date(milliseconds)); dbDate.format("hh:mm:A").split(":");` for this code

Comment: What is the value of `milliseconds`?

Comment: Note the deprecation warning: _"Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date"_ so by explicitly calling `new Date`, you're doing the exact thing that moment is attempting to warn you against doing.

Comment: I've read a bit more of the docs and I was mistaken - moment does (claim to) support a `milliseconds` argument. @JamesThorpe, I would argue that what it's warning about is the implicit fallback to using `Date`, and that using it explicitly is OK.

Comment: Looks like your milliseconds is a string, it needs to be a number. Try `var dbDate = moment(parseInt(milliseconds)); `

Comment: If you do end up using `parseInt`, make sure you [specify a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).